# Error: "Could not find a storyboard named 'main' in bundle NSBundle"

Tags: swift, xcode, interface-builder

when I click the button the application aport and I get "Thread 1: signal SIGABRT".

I also get the following error: "Could not find a storyboard named 'main' in bundle NSBundle"

I've created a simple form with the username text field, password text field, and a submit button.

The text fields have reference outlets that set to the view they are on, however, no reference outlet is created for the button?

Is this normal? as I am getting "Thread 1: signal SIGABRT", and this is the only abnormal thing I found?

Comment: Well, what is the error? SIGABRT is the signal being sent, but usually there is also an error (or error code).

Comment: @SanderSaelmans well, when I click the button the application aport and I get "Thread 1: signal SIGABRT"

Comment: @SanderSaelmans ok I found this: "reason: 'Could not find a storyboard named 'main' in bundle NSBundle"

Comment: do you use a storyboard? If so, you can set it in your Project->Target->Deployment Info->Main Interface

Comment: Could it be that the storyboard name is actually capitalized? Try opening a storyboard called `Main`

Comment: can you share your code or you can Set Main instead of main in bundle Name.

Answer (score 1):

The problem was in this line:

```
let mainStoryBoard = UIStoryboard(name: "main", bundle: Bundle.main)
```

so I changed it to:

```
let mainStoryBoard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: Bundle.main)
```

and it worked!

Answer (score 1):

This error has come up randomly for me a couple of times with Xcode 11. One day my iPad app is building and running fine, the next - with no changes to the code or project whatsoever - I will see a warning at build time:

`no rule to process file '...$filename.xcdatamodeld'...`

and then when the app runs it will break immediately with this message:

`Could not find a storyboard named 'Main' in bundle NSBundle`

It is an older iPad app project that has been updated for newer Xcode versions over the years. The project uses Core Data and the workspace includes several CocoaPods, a mix of Objective-C, Swift as well as XIBs and Storyboards.

Over the last 6 months it's happened a few times and I've wasted a lot of time on this, even recreating the project, changing project configuration as suggested around StackOverflow, etc. but the only thing that works is to follow the steps below. I'm not sure what step actually fixes the problem, but so far I've discovered that I have to do all three!

1. Reset Xcode and clean the project using [this Gist](https://gist.github.com/maciekish/66b6deaa7bc979d0a16c50784e16d697)
2. Delete the app from the Simulator
3. Restart my MacBook